# HTML 5 image not appearing on hover

Tags: html

I am rebuilding my intranet site to be responsive just for fun and now the code for my image hover is not working. I have tried to rebuild it several different ways with no success. All images are by default the same height and width. The movie-hover image is supposed to hover over the movie images with opacity to still be able to see the image behind it. The CSS is really stripped down as i have been messing around with it.  Any help would be much appreciated.

HTML5

```
<div id="boxd"> <!-- Start of Boxd 1 -->

    <!-- start of row 1 -->

      <div id="rowd">
       <div id="movie-hover"><a href="a-good-day-to-die-hard.html"><img src="css/images/a-good-day-to-die-hard.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='css/images/movie-hover.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='css/images/a-good-day-to-die-hard.jpg'" alt="Movie cover image of A Good Day to Die Hard" /></a></div>
       <div id="movie-hover"><a href="tammy.html"><img src="css/images/tammy.jpg" alt=""/></a></div>
       <div id="movie-hover"><a href="xxx-the-return-of-xander-cage.html"><img src="css/images/xxx-the-return-of-xander-cage.jpg" alt="Movie cover image"/></a></div>
       <div id="movie-hover"><a href="secondhand-lions.html"><img src="css/images/secondhand-lions.jpg" alt="Movie cover image"/></a></div>
       <div id="movie-hover"><a href="logan.html"><img src="css/images/logan.jpg" alt="X-Men The Last Stand."/></a></div>
       <div id="movie-hover"><a href="super-troopers.html"><img src="css/images/super-troopers.jpg" alt="Movie cover image"/></a></div>
       <div id="movie-hover"><a href="taken.html"><img src="css/images/taken.jpg" alt="Movie cover image"/></a></div>
       <div id="movie-hover"><a href="gran-torino.html"><img src="css/images/gran-torino.jpg" alt="Movie cover image"/></a></div>
       <div id="movie-hover"><a href="o-brother-where-art-thou.html"><img src="css/images/o-brother-where-art-thou.jpg" alt="Movie cover image"/></a></div>

       <div id="movie-hover"><a href="the-lord-of-the-rings-the-fellowship-of-the-ring.html"><img src="css/images/the-lord-of-the-rings-the-fellowship-of-the-ring.jpg" alt="Movie cover image"/></a></div>
       <div id="movie-hover"><a href="chips.html"><img src="css/images/chips.jpg" alt="Movie cover image"/></a></div>
       <div id="movie-hover"><a href="gladiator.html"><img src="css/images/gladiator.jpg" alt=""/></a></div>
       <div id="movie-hover"><a href="braveheart.html"><img src="css/images/braveheart.jpg" alt="Movie cover image Braveheart 1995"/></a></div>
       <div id="movie-hover"><a href="the-jerk.html"><img src="css/images/the-jerk.jpg" alt="Movie cover image"/></a></div>
       <div id="movie-hover"><a href="the-patriot.html"><img src="css/images/the-patriot.jpg" alt="Movie cover image"/></a></div>
       <div id="movie-hover"><a href="the-postman.html"><img src="css/images/the-postman.jpg" alt="Movie cover image"/></a></div>
       <div id="movie-hover"><a href="warcraft.html"><img src="css/images/warcraft.jpg" alt="Movie cover image" /></a></div>
       <div id="movie-hover"><a href="dune.html"><img src="css/images/dune.jpg" alt="Movie cover image" /></a></div>

       </div>    
     </div>
```

CSS

```
#rowd {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#boxd {
    text-align: center;
}

#boxd img {
    height: 48%;
    width: 48%;
}

#movie-hover {
    display: inline;
}

#movie-hover img:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Comment: can u post a fiddle for your current code

Answer (score 1):

All your images are JPEGs, a format which doesn't support transparency or translucency.

When you set the background image, it is completely covered up by the foreground image.

---

The opacity applies to *the whole element*, not just the foreground of it.

---

Toggle the `src` attribute with JavaScript instead.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information, I think I did the JavaScript right. I just did an onmouseover/out, works good to change the image but I don't know how to use this affect to work with opacity between the two images, so you see both on top of each other. I updated the code here to my current configuration, only applying to the first image atm. Should I change all my images to GIF's?